# I am not ble to click on radio button in mentioned webpage by using VBA

Tags: vba

web page link- http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurywelcome.php
Steps -
1.  first Access Link (need to sign in this page , for that you have to sign up it by keying some info (not necessary that it it should be genuine).
2. I want to select One Way trip instead of round trip by selecting radio button- 
for this entire process i have written below code -
but i am not able to check 2nd radio button by using below code

```
Sub tour()
Dim url As String
Dim ie, inpt, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, rd1, passenger As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
url = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercurywelcome.php"
ie.navigate url
While ie.readystate <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
MsgBox "plz set username and password in this code/"
Set inpt = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
For Each a1 In inpt
If a1.getattribute("name") = "userName" Then
a1.Value = "*****"
Exit For
End If
Next
For Each a2 In inpt
If a2.getattribute("name") = "password" Then
a2.Value = "*****"
Exit For
End If
Next
For Each a3 In inpt
If a3.getattribute("name") = "login" Then
a3.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do
If ie.readystate = 4 Then
Exit Do
Else
DoEvents
End If
Loop
'*******facing issue in below code
Set rd1 = ie.document.getelementsbyname("tripType")
For Each a4 In rd1
If a4.getattribute("value") = "oneway" Then
a4.Click
'*************
Exit For
End If
Next
'Set passenger = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("select")
'For Each a5 In passenger
'If a5.getattribute("name") = "passCount" Then
'a5.Value = 3
'Exit For
'End If
'Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most direct way to select the "one-way" radio button

```
    ie.document.all.Item("tripType")(1).Checked = True
```

your method will work too if you change

```
    a4.Click
```

to

```
    a4.Checked = True
```

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately its also showing error(debug) on your code- ie.document.all.Item("tripType")(1).Checked = True

Comment: again, both approaches work on my computer, what error are you getting and on what line?